# Sanitizar un texto pero respetando solo etiquetas html

Tags: php, php7

En PHP:
Pues lo que deseo es en un campo text permitir negrilla, italicas, lineas, encabezados html, etc.
Para guardar en una base de datos, pero previniendo la temida inyección sql y javascript.

Uso:

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

pero lo limpia todo.

¿ qué me recomendáis ?

Comment: Busca información de `PHP Tidy`, `HTML Purifier` y `HtmLawed`, seguro una de esas opciones te servirá.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Triby, he tomado HtmLawd como el más sencillo de usar. De todas formas estoy usando como editor visual ckeditor y parece que hace la limpieza. Escribí un alert de js y mira lo que finalmente se guardó: <p>&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;hola&#39;);&lt;/script&gt;</p>  Así que miraré la docu de ckeditor a ver.

Answer (score 1):

Cecilior, me parece que la mejor forma de hacer lo que necesetias es utilizando el filtro de PHP FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS (https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php) y despues utilizar una sentencia preparada para guardar en la base de datos. De esta forma conservas los tags html y al mismo tiempo previenes inyección de código.